# Can the verb "live" be used in the sense of surviving something?

Tags: word-usage

I have come across the usage of *live* that seems to mean survive, but I checked a few dictionaries and none of them give the definition. I have come across this usage in this [video](https://youtu.be/nzCqlw1bFok). It is at 4 minutes and 25 seconds. Here is the context:

> The Vikings also believed that an honorable death in battle would earn them one-way trip to a glorious afterlife with either the god Odin in Valhalla or the goddess Freja in Folkvangr. If they **lived**, they could not only gain honour for themselves, but also enjoy their share of the loot from the raids.

Could the word *live* be replace with the word *survive* without any effect?

Comment: Here, 'if they lived' apparently just means 'if they were still alive after the battle'.

Comment: Stylistically, ***lived*** is actually better than ***survived*** in this exact context (so you could say the choice has a *slight* effect). You'd normally only talk about ***surviving*** an experience where you were primarily / particularly concerned with ***not dying***. Using ***lived*** instead is far more neutral on that front, and we're supposed to be left with the general impression that to the Vikings, living/dying wasn't important compared to whether they fought "honorably" (bravely, in a just cause,...). *You live or you die, it's all the same.*